How Compare Android Device Date and Time with Actual IST
When a user changes the date or time on their device, I want to display a message showing the current date and time in IST. However, this approach doesn’t work as expected because when the user adjusts the device’s date or time, both variables (the device’s time and IST) end up being the same.
val ALLOWED_TIME_DIFFERENCE = 5 * 60 * 1000L

   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val deviceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val deviceTimeMillis = deviceCalendar.timeInMillis

    val istZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()),
        ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")
    )
    val istTimeMillis = istZonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()

    val deviceDate = deviceCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000 + (deviceCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100 + deviceCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val istDate = istZonedDateTime.toLocalDate().toEpochDay().toInt()

    val dateMismatch = deviceDate != istDate
    val timeDifference = abs(deviceTimeMillis - istTimeMillis)
    val timeMismatch = timeDifference > ALLOWED_TIME_DIFFERENCE

    Log.d("TimeCheck", "Device Time: ${deviceCalendar.time}")
    Log.d("TimeCheck", "IST Time: ${istZonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime()}")
    Log.d("TimeCheck", "Date Mismatch: $dateMismatch, Time Mismatch: $timeMismatch, Time Difference: $timeDifference")

    if (dateMismatch || timeMismatch) {
        showTimeWarning = true
    }
}


There is only one clock on the device. If you want to compare the device clock with the actual time, you'll need to get the latter externally (e.g. from the Internet or GPS). By the way, it's best to avoid legacy classes like Calendar, and just stick to those in the package java.time solely.
